# disabling button to avoid double postback but preserving client side validation

Tags: asp.net

I'm getting an occasional double postback. I'd like to disable the "save" button client-side after the user clicks it once, but I have to make sure the client side validators are valid before I disable it. How do I check this in clientside code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:
[Client Validation Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb52a4x0.aspx#ClientSideValidation_ClientValidationObjectModel)

Use Page_IsValid to check that the all validation are valid or not on client side.

Use Page_ClientValidate() function for validating a particular validation group.

```
var isGroupValid = Page_ClientValidate("ValidationGroup");
```

Comment: Can the page_isvalid variable be used to validate one validation group?

Comment: Use Page_ClientValidate() function for validating a particular validation group.                                                   `var isGroupValid = Page_ClientValidate("ValidationGroup");`